# Looping over a list of lists

Tags: r, list, loops

I have the following code:

```
condition_1_top_genes = list("abc", "def", "efg")
condition_2_top_genes = list("a35", "2353", "rea3")
condition_3_top_genes = list("fae", "wai", "wtes")

top_genes = list(condition_1_top_genes, 
                 condition_2_top_genes,
                 condition_3_top_genes)

genotypes <- list("genotype1" = genotype1, 
                  "genotype2" = genotype2,
                  "genotype3"  genotype3)

for (i in length(genotypes)){
  for (j in ????){
    FeaturePlot(genotypes[[i]], features = ??)
  }
}
```

genotypes is a list of Seurat objects.

In the outer loop I'm looping over the Seurat objects, for the inner loop I want to loop over each of the lists in top_genes. So when i = 1 I want j to move along condition_1_top_genes, then when i=2, I want j to move along condition_2_top_genes, etc.

Any help on this syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, usually in R we try and avoid for-loops, as most common operations are vectorised. Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do, and make your example reproducible? (We don't have `gene1`, `gene2` etc so we can't replicate `top_genes`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What is `genotype1`, `genotype2`, etc

Comment: I said in my post, genotypes is a list of Seurat objects.  But that part is working...I loop over that list multiple times successfully.  I just need to know how to move along the list of list of top_genes.

Comment: @WantaghMomma  Is it one feature at a time from top_genes

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to test.  Perhaps  `for (i in seq_along(genotypes)){
  
    FeaturePlot(genotypes[[i]], features = top_genes[[i]])
  }`

Comment: I figured it out:
```
for (i in 1:length(e2f.conditions)){
  for (j in 1:length(top_genes)){
    print(FeaturePlot(e2f.conditions[[i]], features = top_genes[[i]][[j]]))
  }
}
```
just needed the double brackets around the i and j.

Answer (score 0):

`[`, wouldn't extract the `list` element, we need `[[` to go inside the list and extract as vector.  Also, we can use a single `for` loop instead of nested as `top_genes` showed is not a nested `list` but a `list` of `vector`s

```
for(i in seq_along(top_genes)) {
     top_genes[[i]] <- seq_along(top_genes[[i]]) * 3
}
```

Comment: Here's a bit more code:
```
gene1 <- list('a', 'b', 'c')
gene2 <- list('d', 'e', 'f')

top_genes <- list("gene1" = gene1, "gene2" = gene2)
```
What I want to do is loop over top_genes and print the contents of the gene1 list, then move onto gene2 and print its contents.

Comment: @WantaghMomma your new requirement is not clear.  Perhaps `for(i in seq_along(top_genes)) print(top_genes[[i]])`

Comment: Thanks...sorry if I'm not being clear.  The actual data can't be shared and would take me a long time to make fake code to share.  Thanks anyway

Comment: @WantaghMomma Please consider to provide a small reproducible example  I guess I already showed the code for your posted question

Comment: I'm going to try...I'm editing the original post.  The new code isn't reproducible but all I need to know is the syntax to use in place of the ????.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> condition_1_top_genes = list("abc", "def", "efg")
> condition_2_top_genes = list("a35", "2353", "rea3")
> condition_3_top_genes = list("fae", "wai", "wtes")
>
> top_genes = list(condition_1_top_genes, 
>                 condition_2_top_genes,
>                 condition_3_top_genes)
> ```

If I understand you correctly, you'd probably want to change the way you define the list `top_genes`.

```
# Define genes in character vector, allowing you to use concise syntax later on
condition_1_top_genes = c("abc", "def", "efg")
condition_2_top_genes = c("a35", "2353", "rea3")
condition_3_top_genes = c("fae", "wai", "wtes")

# Define list elements with names
top_genes = list(
  condition_1_top_genes = condition_1_top_genes, 
  condition_2_top_genes = condition_2_top_genes,
  condition_3_top_genes = condition_3_top_genes
)
```

Now you `top_genes` is a named list, you can access list elements in `top_genes` with [[""]] operator.

```
> top_genes[["condition_1_top_genes"]]
[1] "abc" "def" "efg"

# with paste0 function, you can access arbitrary list element
> i=1
> top_genes[[paste0("condition_",i,"_top_genes")]]
[1] "abc" "def" "efg"

# To access jth gene in condition_1_top_genes
> j=1
> top_genes[[paste0("condition_",i,"_top_genes")]][j]
[1] "abc"
```

So in your for loop, you can do:

```
for (i in length(genotypes)){
  for (j in length(top_genes[[paste0("condition_",i,"_top_genes")]])){
    FeaturePlot(genotypes[[i]], features = top_genes[[paste0("condition_",i,"_top_genes")]][j])
  }
}
```